# How to do a URLConnection Request as it was in Incognito Mode

Tags: java, urlconnection, incognito-mode

I have the following class:

```java
public class GetHtmlContent {

    public static String GetHtml(){

        String content = null;
        URLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            connection =  new URL("https://www.tomshardware.com/").openConnection();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
            content = scanner.next();
        }catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

How do I go about so that each request is considered as **NEW**, same as I was in Chrome's **Incognito Mode**

*Note: The site is just an example*

Comment: Well you could make a good start by closing your streams. See also [`HttpURLConnection.disconnect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect--).

Comment: Hey there, Thanks for the answer. I changed it from URLConnection to HttpURLConnection and I added a disconnect clause at the finally section. However, the issue is still not resolved, and I'm still being served personalized content. Any other ideas or second step?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html - you might get away with the bottom example, just instead of `MyCookiePolicy`, use the built-in `CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_NONE`. Alternatively you may re-initialize the cookie-handler things between the "incognito"sessions.

Comment: Try to intercept the request and response with Fiddler.

Answer (score 4):

Without any specific additional setup your code shouldn't transfer cookies.

This is best tested with a HTTPS proxy. So if your code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GetHtml();
    GetHtml();
    GetHtml();
}
```

you can see at all three calls that there are no cookies transferred.

[image: no cookies without special setup]

**Adding CookieHandler**

If you are adding a cookie handler like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

    GetHtml();
    GetHtml();
    GetHtml();
}
```

then the situation is different. Only in the first call there are no cookies, after the first calls further calls are transferring the cookies.

[image: cookies with cookie handler]

**Recommendation**

So it's recommended to set a proxy to see what actual data your program is transferring.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cache to false.

```
connection.setUseCaches(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between Chrome and Chrome incognito mode is that it doesn't share cookies and other storage mechanisms. Chrome in incognito mode also doesn't persist anything, so once Chrome is closed, anything that the website could have tried to store in your browser will be lost.

In other words, the moment you create a new connection and you don't send any previous cookies, it's similar to the incognito mode. Mind you that as long as you keep the connection, it's ok to send the cookies.

I'm not sure what is your intent, but mind you that a website can have additional ways of detecting duplicate connections like IP, user-agent version if provided, OS if provided, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First it is important to understand how Chrome's [Incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) [works](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7440301):

> - Chrome won't save your: browsing history, cookies and site data, or information entered in forms.
> - Files you download and bookmarks you create will be kept.
> - Your activity **isn’t hidden** from websites you visit, your employer or school, or your internet service provider.

A `URLConnection`, in general, does not:

- Save browsing history
- Save cookies and site data (you can save cookies using [CookieManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/CookieManager.html))
- Save information entered in forms

It also does not save or download files by default. Neither are bookmarks  relevant here.

Furthermore, it is important to understand that the Incognito mode is not anything like a VPN -- your ISP, the sites you browse, etc. all can see your computer's IP address, your browser's agent string, etc.

So the "newness" of requests from a network perspective is more like an illusion. However, when in Incognito, locally nothing will be retained about your browsing sessions so if you login to, say, your bank account on a public machine (which you should never do IMHO) it is safer to use Incognito mode, because as soon as you close the Incognito window(s), all your session information is cleared and other users of that public machine can't access it.

So, in short, you don't have to do anything special to be in "incognito" mode when using a `URLConnection`. In fact, the opposite is correct: you need to write additional code to make a Java program remember the links it has so far visited or to retain cookies, etc.